# When will updating the Oberdiek bundle be stable?

Tags: oberdiek

I, and several other people (I'm not quoting references), have had problems with using `tlmgr update -all` for updating concerning the `oberdiek` bundle. In general, after the update there are missing packages. When will the partitioning of `oberdiek` into individual packages be complete and workable?

Comment: .... when the hurlyburly is done! (Macbeth l,1). ;-) But in earnest: it should be ok now. There will be only more splits if one of the remaining packages need an update.

Comment: I'm surprised you were affected actually. Anyone installing a standard texlive shouldn't see any difference other than some behind the scenes re-arrangement of the input tree. It does affect people who just install a minimal texlive with only the packages they need (usually part of testing configurations) as they have to install any split off packages that they use. At no point was the distributed collection as on ctan unworkable (with missing or duplicated packages) although timing through an unknown set of mirrors may mean that there were transient issues as everything distributed.

Comment: I had problems, too, to the point I reinstalled TeXLive from scratch. Maybe the server I first chose was not completely updated. Fortunately, now everything is fine.

Comment: The only texlive people I've heard that had problems were users with non-full installations, probably because the split out package will not be auto installed. The users with the most issues seems to have been miktex users.

Answer (score 6):

Originally there were (I think) 97 dtx files in the bundle, there are now 43, so by some measure only a little over half way through, however there are no plans to pro-actively split any more. However if issues are raised that require updating any of the remaining 43, probably I'll split the updated package into its own repository rather than updating in place in the oberdiek bundle.

It is somewhat surprising that as an end user you noticed any of the changes at all, there were never missing packages on ctan, just files moved out to their own directories, so anyone with a full texlive distribution shouldn't really have noticed anything other than some internal re-arrangements in the input tree.

People who install minimal texlive with only specific packages installed (often as part of continuous integration test builds) were affected as they needed to adjust the list of packages installed. That is why the ctan-announce message for each update listed the set of packages that you might need to install.

It may have been that you were on a slow mirror that took a while to get all the packages in sync, given the distributed nature of package installations, it's hard to control that.

Comment: Thank you David, and the Oberdiek, TeXLive and MikTeX teams for maintaining all these packages. We are very grateful. Happy holidays.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that part of my problem was that my computer was having a series of hissy fits, but all seems OK now. I use the mirror at Warwick University. I grew up within a stone's throw of the site and watched it being built. I'm now within walking distance and could almost use a heliograph to access the mirror (but that wouldn't work --- if only). I suppose that it is electronic distance, not geographical, that makes the difference to download speeds.

Comment: @PeterWilson oh that's same mirror as I use, no idea why you saw issues then.